# Is it possible to use ReasonReact to build a single component?

Tags: reason, reason-react

I'm investigating the possibility to use Reason and React in an old (first commit 2003) legacy project. The approach has to be evolutionary and step-by-step. Does ReasonReact cover this use-case? Or is it mostly used to build apps from scratch?

I'm a bit surprised there's no `make`-like command to build a specific .re-file into a .bs.js file. Or I missed it in the docs...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReasonReact can migrate a project one file (i.e. module) at a time. Add `bs-platform` to your `package.json`'s `dependencies` section, add a `bsconfig.json` file with the correct options, and add a build command (e.g. `bsb -clean-world && bsb -make-world`) to your build pipeline, and it will build all ReasonReact source files and produce output JS.

Comment: OK, this works, but the built module cannot find the "react" module, which is loaded via CDN. Is this possible, or do I have to build everything in one bundle?

Comment: The ReScript toolchain is designed to work within the standard npm workflow, i.e. it needs something to do module resolution. So you will need to use a bundler.

Comment: Testing "es6-global" as module type, still get the `"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".` error